# Where is the x icon in this HTML and Sass (or equivalent CSS)?

Tags: html, css, sass

I do not understand where the x icon is defined in the following HTML and Sass. I had expected something like an fa unicode, e.g. `content: "\f00d"`, but content is empty as seen below. Where does the icon that you can see in the image after the username come from?

[image: x-icon]

```
      .logout
        padding: 0 12px
        position: relative

        a
          position: absolute
          height: 50px
          width: 20px
          top: -16px
          left: 0
          cursor: pointer
          padding: 0

          &:before,
          &:after
            width: 2px
            height: 12px
            left: 10px
            top: 50%
            margin-top: -6px
            content: ""
            position: absolute
            background-color: #AAAAAA

          &:before
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg)
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)
            transform: rotate(-45deg)


          &:after
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg)
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)
            transform: rotate(45deg)

          &:hover
            &:before,
            &:after
              background-color: #111111
```

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>other items...</li>
        <li>
            <span>
                <span>User: Pao</span>
                <span class="logout">
                    <a href="/logout"></a>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>other items...</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `inspect elements` tool?

Comment: Yes, certainly, and there is no more than the given code, as far as i can see. If i remove the (empty) content, the icon disappears. But i still do not see where the x is coming from.

Comment: It's from the pseudo elements then. See the `transform: rotate(-45deg)` and `transform: rotate(45deg)`. It's basically two vertical lines rotated by 45 degrees which have a grey background by `background-color: #AAAAAA`.

Comment: ```transform: rotate``` defines rotation of an element, as far as i know, but you write "two vertical lines", @BehRouz. So where do two lines come from?

Comment: Oh, `pseudo elements` (:before, and :after). read them more carefully. you will see the lines, 2 pixels wide and 12 pixels high.

Comment: Ok, i see now. Thank you very much for explaining. If you post it as an answer i can accept.

Comment: To provide an appropriate answer, can you provide the same code into an codpen link?

Comment: Sure Pao. No, It's fine. Thanks.

Comment: @passionFinder, sorry, i do not have a Codepen account.

Comment: @Pao, No Problem, Hope you got the answer.

Comment: In this case, @BehRouz, i hope it is ok to accept the answer that cites your explanation.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As @BehRouz mentioned,

```
      &:before,
      &:after
        width: 2px
        height: 12px
        left: 10px
        top: 50%
        margin-top: -6px
        content: ""
        position: absolute
        background-color: #AAAAAA
      &:before
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg)
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)
        transform: rotate(-45deg)


      &:after
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg)
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)
        transform: rotate(45deg)
```

This code refers to the close button.
Please inspect the X icon and you will see the above code on the right side of the inspect tool.

Comment: For me though, the important part was "lines, 2 pixels wide and 12 pixels high", as i had not realized that the pseudo elements had a width and height.